# How to set different position for icon and text inside button?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have button element which have icon and text inside of it. I would like to position icon to left side of button and text center of button.

Here is my button element:

```
<button className='button'>
  <span className='buttonSpan>
    <span className='buttonIcon'>
      <Icon />
    </span>
    <span className='buttonText'>
      Next
    </span>
  </span>
</button>
```

I tried to position each of them with `justify-content` but that doesn't work. Like this:

```
.button {
  .buttonSpan {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    .buttonIcon {
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .buttonText {
      justify-content: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change button element to div, you can use css-grid:

```css
.button {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 10em;
  padding: 1em .5em;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
.buttonIcon {
  justify-self: start;
}
.buttonText {
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class='button'>
  <i class="buttonIcon fas fa-cannabis"></i>
  <span class='buttonText'>
    Next
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! I'm using a library which has pre-made buttons and I noticed button was actually li-element. So I created div inside of that and now it's perfect. Thank you!